# Wordpress CF7 form email direct based on subject chosen

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Im a bit of noob here as it relates to PHP so bear with me, but I'll try to over communicate all the info to help as much as possible  I have a Wordpress site with a CF7 form, its super basic, literally 4 fields, name, email, phone, and subject.  the subject has a drop down with 7 options.  the default is the first option, so theres no way to default to no choice.

Heres the Form itself:

Shortcode: [contact-form-7 id="66720" title="Contact Us - New"]

Form:

```
<label>Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
[text* your-name]

<label>Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
[email* your-email]

<label>Phone<span class="required">*</span></label>
[tel* your-phone]

<label>Subject<span class="required">*</span></label>
[select* your-subject "Subject 1" "Subject 2" "Subject 3" "Subject 4" "Subject 5" "Subject 6" "Subject 7"]

[honeypot info nomessage:true]

[submit "Submit"]
```

Ive tried this 2 ways, using if statements and switch statements. They are in the functions.php file.  Both dont work but in different ways (explained below).

Heres the first:

```
if ($cf7->id == 66720) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data ('your-subject');

    if ($posted_data = 'Subject1') 
            $recipient = 'email1@....com';
    
    elseif ($posted_data = 'Subject2') 
            $recipient = 'email2@....com';
    
    elseif ($posted_data = 'Subject3')
            $recipient = 'email3@....com';
    
    elseif ($posted_data ='Subject4') 
            $recipient = 'email4@....com';
    
    elseif ($posted_data = 'Subject5') 
            $recipient = 'email5@....com';
    
    elseif ($posted_data = 'Subject6') 
            $recipient = 'email6@....com';
    
    elseif ($posted_data = 'Subject7') 
            $recipient = 'email7@....com';
```

Result: with this function it just ignores the if statement completely and sends the email to the first option (email1@) regardless of what subject line is chosen.

Heres the second:

```
 if ($cf7->id == 66720) {
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $subject = $submission->get_posted_data ('your-subject');

    switch ($subject) {
        case 'Subject 1';
            $recipient = 'email1@...';
            break;
    
        case 'Subject 2';
            $recipient = 'email2@...';
            break;
    
        case 'Subject 3';
            $recipient = 'email3@...';
            break;
    
        case 'Subject 4';
            $recipient = 'email4@...';
            break;
    
        case 'Subject 5';
            $recipient = 'email5@...';
            break;
    
        case 'Subject 6'; 
            $recipient = 'email6@...';
            break;
    
        case 'Subject 7';
            $recipient = 'email7@...';
    }
```

Result: with this function the form wont send at all.  I get an error on the form: "There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later."  The form does save in Wordpress however.  The only way i can get the form to work is to add // before one of the subjects, such as "case //'subject7'..." and the form will send but will always default to that.  I understand that is an over riding default, but i dont know why it wouldnt use the switch function without it.

Code prior to the switch/ if statement is:

```
function reselect_cf7_email_based_on_subject($cf7 = null)
```

{

```
  if (!isset($cf7)) {
    $cf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
}
```

Code after the switch/if statement is:

```
 $mail_settings = $cf7->get_properties('mail');
    $mail_settings['mail']['recipient'] = $recipient;
    $cf7->set_properties($mail_settings);

}

return $cf7;
```

Im really hoping I am missing something basic and someone much smarter that me will see the simple fix.  Thanks!

Comment: where did you hook your `reselect_cf7_email_based_on_subject` function?

Comment: Your first attempt is using the assignment operator `=` all over the conditions, where it should be a _comparison_ instead.

Comment: @JoyKumarBera the hook was prior to the if or switch statement, so:

    function reselect_cf7_email_based_on_subject($cf7 = null)
    {

    if (!isset($cf7)) {
        $cf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
    }

    
    if ($cf7->id == 66720) {
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        $subject = $submission->get_posted_data ('your-subject');

        if ($subject == 'Billing')

Comment: @CBroe update actually, I changed to a comparison statement, so if ($posted_data =='Subject 1') the full script is being ignored and the emails are being sent to the original email address in the contact form settings in CF7

Comment: Likely `$posted_data` does not contain what you think it should then. Make a debug output of that value, let the script `die` right after, and check the response. (If the form is submitted via AJAX, then check via the browser dev tools network panel.)

Comment: @CBroe thanks, thats exactly what it is. I added a 'else {$recipient = email@email.com} and it is defaulting to that, so it looks like it does not recognize the subjects in the get_posted_data output.  thought that would be the easiest part of this since it seems to be clearly defined in the code in the form. trying to figure out how to run a debug output .and will let you know once i do and get info. i reviewed the debug.log and nothing of note is in there

Comment: @CBroe definitely the issue.  something coming from the form itself.  i switched one the else if statements to say [your-name] = 'Robert', submitted a form and it went to the correct email.  furthermore if i use a comparison indicator '==' for all the if statements i get an error.  if I add a default at the end it clears the error, which tells me it is either not liking the 'your-subject' or the subject types themselves.  Ive reviewed the form up and down and dont see anything glaring with the code, but thats definitely the culprit so far. I assume its something to do with the dropdown field

Comment: Where/how is the execution of the code you have shown above triggered? Have you tried hooking into `wpcf7_before_send_mail`, as the example under https://contactform7.com/2020/07/28/accessing-user-input-data/ shows?

Comment: This feature is available directly from the contact form using pipes. https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

Comment: @HowardE yup i found that out last night, and is the solution I went with.  the original code by another developer was a bit too complicated for what was needed.  Used recipient with pipes, but the one issue I was finding was when the email was delivered, it wouldnt show the Subject selected to the recipient, rather just the email address. (there was a couple of the selections that go to the same email address) I solved this by using _raw_recipient in the email that went to the recipient.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for your help with all of this!  Was definitely an experience!